# Mailchimp failing to get LeadPages subscription

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

I'm creating a LeadBox and would like the subscription details to populate my MailChimp List. The API appears to be working (e.g. the leadbox > integration settings dropdown populates with my MailChimp list), the leadbox appears to be working fine, but my mailchimp list fails to get the subscription. What am I missing?

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no errors, but the users aren't showing up on your list, you probably have Double-Opt In turned on, which requires your users to confirm their subscription before they appear in your list.

Check out this page for how to turn of double-opt-in for [LeadPages](https://support.leadpages.net/hc/en-us/articles/203522470-MailChimp-Integration-With-Single-Opt-In).